# Visual Studio Error when creating and saving Galileo Wiring Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intel-galileo, windowsondevices

When I create a new Galileo Wiring App Project, the create window is missing fields as displayed in the image below.
[image: Create Dialog Missing Fields]

I can create the project, but if I try to save the project or solution I get the following sequence of dialogs:
[image: Save Project Dialog]
[image: The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported]

I've tried restarting software and computer.

I've tried uninstalling the Visual Studio Extension and reinstalling.

I've tried repair/uninstall/re-install on both the Windows Developer Program for IoT software, and Visual Studio.  I am running Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 3 Version 12.0.30723.00.

I have no problem creating other C++ projects, only this template has an issue.  I can add the C++ Wiring SDK from Nuget, but would have to setup the basic project requirements from scratch and cannot find any guides on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I had an option changed from the default that wasn't compatible with this project type.

[image: Save new projects when created unchecked.]

Turning off the `Save new projects when created.` options allows for "Temporary Projects".  Useful when you have a solution with multiple projects and want to add another, but aren't sure if you want it there permanently (for testing something out).

Seems this setting was keeping the template from providing options to save the project, and then once created it could not be saved at all. Checking the option highlighted in the photo solved the problem.

Comment: This same setting also affects new "Visual C++ for Linux Development" projects.  When "Save new projects when created" is unchecked, then saving any new Linux project will get the error "The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported."  I'm including the text of the error message here to make it easier for others to find via search engines.  nbering's tip helped me when the VCLinux team couldn't!

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad this helped someone else! I actually set the text from the error message in the alt text for the image to help make it searchable.

Answer (score 0):

I know we already talked about it, but here are some more things to try;

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246896

The bottom line is when the template was installed, either its com registration failed, or it registered the wrong .dll.   Finding out which will take some work, and uninstalling and re-installing usually fixes it, but I know you already tried that.

The next thing to do is see if you can find the log file that gets created during the install of the IoT msi.  It 'should' have a message in it regarding the registration failure.

I will spend some time on this and let you know what I find.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I couldn't find any errors of any kind in the installation or operational logs, but I did eventually find the solution (just an option in Visual Studio's settings).